# On independence of R.V

Tags: probability

We know that if $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)$ and if the ranges of $X$ and $Y$ are not dependent then X,Y are independent iff $f(x,y)= f(x) g(y)$ for some f,g .

Now, can we get same result, if we instead have

$$ P(X \leq x, Y > y) = f(x) g(y) $$

That is, if we have the above, does this imply that the random variables are independent?

Comment: Did you mean $P(X\leq x,Y>y)=P(X\leq x)P(Y>y)$? If so then yes you will have same result.

Comment: i meant for some function f and  g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X\leq x, Y>y)=f(x)g(y)$ implies $P(X\leq x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}P(X\leq x, Y>y)=f(x)g(-\infty).$ Similarly taking $x\rightarrow \infty$ we get $P(Y>y)=f(\infty)g(y).$ Also taking both the limits simultaneously we get $f(\infty)g(-\infty)=\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}P(X\leq x, Y>y)=1.$

So we get $P(X\leq x)P(Y>y)=f(x)g(-\infty)f(\infty)g(y)=f(x)g(y)=P(X\leq x, Y>y).$ From there just taking derivatives w.r.t. both  $x$ and $y$ we get $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_Y(y).$

Comment: Passing by infinities is not needed, simply use $$P(X\leqslant x,Y>y)=P(X\leqslant x)-P(X\leqslant x,Y\leqslant y)$$